# Android mute microphone while not in call

Tags: android, microphone, android-audiomanager

I want to mute a microphone for quite some time, say a day. However, when a user makes a call or somebody calls, I want to enable the microphone and disable it afterwards. I did this:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE); 
audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(true);
```

This code works except in a situation after a call. After the call, the microphone is enabled. I suspect that a phone app can enable microphone again and so can other apps. How can I make microphone muted after the call? And is there a way to restrict other apps from enabling microphone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obliviously the Phone App enables the Microphone before answer/plac a call, but it doesn't restore the previous state because the normal state for the Mic is to be Enabled.

You can use two different approaches: (1) set a Listener that detect voicecall end and restore the previous state or (2) if your device has  Root Permissions and the Mic is present in "dev/inout/eventX" (where "X" is a progressive number but it is different between devices and even between reboots) you could open it in Exclusive mode, in this way no-one could open/use it again until you release the "lock". However an App (the Phone App or WhatsApp when the recording button is pressed) could crash if it doesn't manage very well this case.

However I would notice you that the "AudioManager.setMicrophoneMute()" is implementation dependant and could not work on all Android versions (it depends of the Minifacturer).

Comment: Unfortunately, devices don't have root permissions. Also, is it a good way to mute the microphone, say once a 5 seconds? AudioManager.setMicrophoneMute() works on my devices, but I need to make sure that no other app can unmute the microphone

Comment: Unfortunately there is a limit in your implementation because starting from ANdroid 6 Marshmallow there is a check where "AudioManager.setMicrophoneMute()" should executed: it checks if a Voicecall is currently active and it denied the method to change Mic while it is in this status. Voicecall and VoIP Apps always set the PhoneMode to IN_CALL/IN_COMMUNICATION so the Mic is always working there. Maybe other Apps could use MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION as they wish. So you CAN mute it avery 5 seconds but it's not guaranteed the Mic remains mute